# ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de down?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

From here, the mirror at   ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de looks down since yesterday (20180516).
Has it been removed officially, or is it a temporary issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291470/ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de-down-?/) by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
[wiki/Mirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors) also shows there's something up with it. Perhaps something to ask the maintainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was referring to the binary packages mirror. In the mean time, the package mirror at Freiburg seems to be back up.
http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors refers to mirrors of the wiki which is a separate issue.

---

Originally posted by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) with karma: 148 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
Both hostnames resolve to the same IP, so there would be no difference.

But seeing as it's already up again, doesn't matter.